# regex use patterns to extract a string (two values between digits and numbers)

Tags: regex, r, string

I know there are people who asked how to get strings inside a text but I am not familiar with `regex` at all until today.
I have merged a set of data files and put the filename as a column. I needed to extract the X and Y coordinates from the filename as well and put it in two columns.

Example:

```
name1_name2_20151028_0_R02X139Y310_1 expected output is
X      Y
139    310
```

I tried:

```
pattern <- "^name1_name2_(\\d+)_0_R(\\d+)X(\\d+)Y(\\d+)_1.*txt$"
```

and did not succeed when I tried to run for grep, so I could not go any further.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide complete self contained code and all inputs that when copied and pasted into an R session reproduces the precise error you got.

Comment: Something like this? `gsub(".*X([0-9]+)Y([0-9]+)_.*", "\\1, \\2", YourString)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it out into 2 steps:

```
1. Create a regular expression to extract the information   

gsub("(.*X)([0-9]+)(Y)([0-9]+)(.*)", "\\2, \\4", df$col)

2. Split the information into two columns by the comma

library(splitstackshape) 
df=cSplit(df, "col", ",")
```

Comment: Why do ```gsub(".*X([0-9]+)Y([0-9]+)_.*", "\\1, \\2", YourString)``` that @Ananda gave and ```gsub("(.*X)([0-9]+)(Y)([0-9]+)(.*)", "\\2, \\4", df$col``` give the same result?

Comment: @Nancy each `()` is a "capture group" which are number sequentially, so they are capturing the same thing using different numbers of groups

Comment: @rawr is correct. Was this helpful to answering your question?